# Python Pandas. How to use rolling window to subtract

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

i want to take a rolling window of say size 8 and subtract it by its mean.  i thought it would be simple to do this.

```
df[column].rolling(8,min_periods=4)-df[column].rolling(8,min_periods=4).mean()
```

obviously this is wrong.  i read the docs here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html

so i thought to use .apply()

```
def dumby(x):
    return x

df[column].rolling(8,min_periods=4).apply(dumby)-df[column].rolling(8,min_periods=4).mean()
```

this does not work either and does not seem like good code to me.

i modified dumby to the following below but it does not work.  it states a float is required as the error.

```
def dumby(x):
t=[]
for i in x:
   t.append(i)
j=[float(y) for y in t]   
return j
```

any help is appreciated.

Edit added table for clarification on what i am asking.  looking to have end values.

[image]

EDIT 2:  Working with a 100k + rows so the window method is important.

Comment: Can you create some dummy data with expected output?

Comment: added thanks.  just an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
df['col'] - df['col'].rolling(8).mean()
```

Comment: thanks.  one of those questions that once you see answered you feel dumb.  Thanks to Scott Boston too you had it.